# Java and C++ (VS) RSA encryption

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, encryption

I am trying to  make 2 apllications talk to each other using RSA. First one is in c++ and the second one is in java. First one needs to send a public key to the java application. I am using a

```
CryptExportKey(m_hCryptKey, NULL, PUBLICKEYBLOB, 0, pbKeyBlob, &dwBlobLen);
```

function for this.
In java application I was trying to import it using this function:

```
public PublicKey getPublicKeyFromBytes(byte[] keyBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeyFactory keyFactory;
    keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
}
```

It throws InvalidKeySpecException. Could you please tell me how am I supposed to Import/Export keys?

Comment: Clearly the C++ side isn't sending just raw key bytes, but why aren't you using SSL?

Comment: CryptExportKey returns data in a non-standard, proprietary, Microsoft-defined format.

Comment: @GregS Possibly for this time only, [Microsoft did go through the motions of specifying the structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so it should be relatively simple to parse (using `ByteBuffer` would be a good idea, as it all seems to use little-endian encoding).

Comment: If you post some (example) public key blob I can see if I can decode it...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a decoder for the Microsoft RSA public key structure. Fortunately [that structure is well defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that it uses little-endian encoding so you could first wrap the structure in a `ByteBuffer` [setting the order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) to little-endian.

Then you should convert the public exponent and modulus parts to a `BigInteger` using `BigInteger.valueOf(1, bigEndianByteArray)`. Trick is to get the bytes in the `bigEndianByteArray` in the correct order after reading them from the `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer, black? Did you succeed in importing the structure in Java. Please followup on your questions!